# How to use css to render like this image text？

Tags: css

How to use css to render like this image text？Text gradient and text frame color，
I can’t achieve the effect when I write the text frame like this

```css
.text {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #FFFFFF, #EEC09B);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #FFFFFF, #EEC09B);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: #834C21 1px 1px 1px, #834C21 1px -1px 1px, #834C21 -1px 1px 1px, #834C21 -1px -1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">6500<div>
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 2):

I tried to achieve somewhat similar effect. I wrapped the text in a `span` to give styling to text.

```css
.text {
  background: #FCE2C1;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #86441C;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.text span {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #FCE2C1);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 1px #86441C) drop-shadow(0 5px 1px #86441C40) drop-shadow(0 0 3px #86441C);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <span>6500</span>
</div>
```